# C# Signalr - An error occured while sending the request

Tags: c#

So I'm trying out SignalR, for this project I'm doing. And I don't really understand the .WithUrl paramater in HubConnectionBuilder. How do I know which URL to specify, if I want to host on localhost?

My HUB:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace SignalRChat.MyHub
{
    public class MyHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("SendMessage", user, message);
        }
    }
}
```

My program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client;
using Owin;
using SignalRChat.MyHub;
using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Owin.Cors;

namespace SignalRChat
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        HubConnection connection;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .WithUrl("http://localhost:8080/MyHub")
                .Build();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                await connection.StartAsync();
                //await connection.InvokeAsync("SendMessage", textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
                //listBox1.Items.Add($"{textBox1.Text}: {textBox2.Text}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

[Error message/Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qOZ5.png)

I've tried searching around the internet, about how to use the .WithUrl, but with no luck. I'm hoping that some of you guys can help a brother out!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try displaying the innerException in your exception handler and see what the detailed error is?

Also, check your SignalR Event Hub (http://localhost:8080/MyHub) is running.

If your SignalR event hub is running then try debugging it and see if it receiving requests in your service hub background task.

Another thing you can check is the URL you are calling is identical to the SignalR hub route configured in your SignalR hub hub service:

```
routes.MapHub<MyHubClass>("/MyHub");
```

Comment: How do I check if it's running? How can I even set up the localhost for my signalr hub?

Comment: I am familiar with how it is setup in .NET Core. Are you using .NET Core?

Comment: I believe it is .NET core it's in winforms applicaton